# Switch Between Windows Authenticated Users On Single Windows Account

Tags: sql-server, security, ms-access, windows, authentication

We have a CRM that has been developed in house in Microsoft Access 2003. We are also in the process of moving from an MS Access backend to a SQL Server backend.

I have been researching different types of authentication for SQL Server and [everything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648648.aspx) suggests sticking to [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode) because it is the most secure and reliable way to connect to SQL Server.

The issue with Windows Authentication is that sometimes I may go out on the floor and login as myself with my permissions in the CRM, and I will be able to manipulate the data I have the authority to reach in our current database. With our new SQL Server database I am planning on using the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669084(v=vs.110).aspx), which means that I will have issues signing into our CRM when the windows user is authenticating with lower permissions, meanwhile I am logging into the applicaton with heightened permissions.

Is there a way I could prompt for a Windows Login for my CRM application or do we have to log out of our domain account and into another to use Windows Authentication.

Comment: I provided a method of doing this over at [so] in Visual Basic, to launch SQL Server Management Studio using a different login; you could modify that code to launch your front-end as a different user.  The code is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24958143/1595565)